# Error while booting after upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04.1 using Software Updater

Tags: 18.04

After upgrading my laptop to Ubuntu 18.04.1 and rebooting, I have five options to choose from the cog wheel beside Sign in button,

1. Gnome
2. Gnome with Xorg
3. Ubuntu
4. Ubuntu with Wayland
5. Unity

And default option was Ubuntu. But after entering the password and sign in button, my laptop froze(Violet Screen).

I forcefully shut down my laptop and chose Gnome and entered password and was able to login. But now if I am clicking on any icon in the Dock Panel my laptop froze again. I was not even able to to open Terminal using keyboard shortcuts. After trying for whole day and after using windows, I logged into Ubuntu again next day and it worked fine in both Gnome and Ubuntu environments. But now again I am unable to use, the problem remains the same.
I am using HP-Pavilion with Nvidia Graphic card and Dual Boot with Windows 10. Linux Kernel 4.15.0-33

Comment: Which video driver is in use? Try to boot, and when you are at the login screen, hit Ctrl-Alt-F3, log in with a user account, and type `lshw -c video`. Please add the info to your original question.

Comment: I have attempted force shutdown 3 to 4 times and now boot process is not able to complete ie., It freezes on the Ubuntu Plymouth screen

Comment: @ejjl I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1085820/865193) link where using the 'nomodeset' helps in booting without freezing at the login page. Once after booted setting the Nvidia proprietary driver in Additional Drivers in settings helped me solve this issue.