# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 on HP Pavillion Power

Tags: 18.04, hp, hp-pavilion

I tried installing Ubuntu on HP Pavilion Power 15 laptop. I had Windows previously installed on the SSD, the installation freezes either at language selection or the screen after. I can't seem to solve the problem with other solutions on the forum. The laptop also has the following specifications:

- 128 Gb SSD
- 1TB HDD
- Nvidia GTX1050 graphics card.

I'd like to install Ubuntu on the SSD drive.

Comment: Usually a frozen installer means you either have a corrupted ISO, a mis-made installer media, or you need to try `nomodeset`. Then the installer works properly on the vast majority of hardware. Since you claim to have tried non-specific "other solutions" without success, please edit your question to clearly explain in detail exactly what you tried, and exactly what led you to believe about each attempt that it did not work.

Comment: You need to assure the following conditions: (1) Booting in UEFI mode (disable CSM in UEFI settings) preferably with Secure Boot disabled to avoid complications with the installation of Nvidia drivers. (2) Use `nomodeset` as mentioned above by editing the "try Ubuntu" option of the first menu and typing it in the same line where "quiet splash" is.

Comment: After installing Ubuntu you may need `nomodeset`as well until you install the Nvidia graphics drivers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [installation of 17.10 freezes on HP Pavillion Power 15-cb0xx](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993354/installation-of-17-10-freezes-on-hp-pavillion-power-15-cb0xx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do this by setting **nomodeset**
I followed the following steps as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993354/installation-of-17-10-freezes-on-hp-pavillion-power-15-cb0xx)

1. disable secure boot in bios
2. boot ubuntu installation image from USB stick
3. on bootmanager press <kbd>e</kbd> and then add "nomodeset" in front of "quiet splash", then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
4. Install Ubuntu
5. After installation remove USB stick and change boot order ubuntu first in BIOS
   once again: in bootmanager press <kbd>e</kbd> and then add "nomodeset" in front of "quiet splash", then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
6. When in desktop, enter terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and edit GRUB to prevent it from always starting with nomodeset:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```

add nomodeset: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

```
sudo update-grub
```

reboot
After that you should be able to running ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and use the same machine.

Finally, I managed to install `ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64`. using these steps:

1. Create a live USB boot using Rufus:

   - Partition scheme: MBR
   - Target system: BIOS or UEFI
2. Install Ubuntu with installation type **Something Else**

If you cannot install on the first attempt, try again.

Currently, I'm trying to update from 16.01 to Ubuntu 18.04.

An alternative suggestion can be found in this article [How to install Ubuntu on HP Pavilion Power 15](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/How-to-install-Ubuntu-on-HP-Pavilion-Power-15/td-p/6750887).

Comment: i also had to install ubuntu 16, then update to ubuntu 18.04 LTS