# Ubuntu 20.04 seems slower then 18.04 on my desktop

Tags: system-installation, nomodeset

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and it seems to have succeeded thanks to "nomodeset" (I had to do it for 18.04 too - using [this manual](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084869/installing-ubuntu-18-04-on-hp-pavillion-power)), updates have been brought in, but I still want to check a few things before I fine-tune it, because I'm not 100% convinced that everything is okay.

I do wonder if I installed Ubuntu on the right disk. I had a choice of two disks (sda and sdb) and chose the larger one. I remember that that has something to do with HDD and SSD.
After rebooting it turns out that Ubuntu 18.04 is still on the smallest disk. Apart from the fact that I don't really need that one (18.04), I wonder if I have chosen the right drive and if I don't have a redundant operating system. Suppose I still put this version on the smaller disk, can I just erase everything of the big one?

I have the impression that things just start up slower (PC startup takes longer, but also Firefox startup), possibly because I have installed on the large disk?

While doing this, I'm also finding out the screens from libre office are hidden behind firefox and difficult to find back.

These are my specifications:

[image of my specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF4Xu.png)

About the installation with nomodeset:

Step 3: "on bootmanager press e and then add "nomodeset" in front of "quiet splash", then CTRL+X"

Here I noticed that the word 'nomodeset' was already in that line, but behind 'quiet splash'. I left it there and copied it at the front and afterwards the installation went smoothly.

Step 5: "After installation remove USB stick and change boot order ubuntu first in BIOS once again: in bootmanager press e and then add "nomodeset" in front of "quiet splash", then CTRL+X"

I tried this (this time the word 'nomodeset' was nowhere) and after that the startup crashed. When I don't do anything here I just start up. So maybe step 5 and 6 (When in desktop, enter terminal with CTRL+ALT+T, and edit GRUB to prevent it from always starting with nomodeset) don't apply anymore in this release?

Anyone who can help me to understand what's going wrong?

Lieven

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 20.4 is enourmous. You need to choose what is best for your PC, as one will work better depending on your hardware. For older PCs 18.04 is recommended. The best you can do is switch the driver for the video card or the video card itself, at least for inexperienced users. This is done from the "Activities -> Software & Updates -> Additional drivers". If a driver is available for your video card. Otherwise you will see nothing in this menu. You have to wait a little, because sometimes the driver list is loaded slowly.